# python HTTP POST fails with "only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not 1"

Tags: java, python, xml, http-post, xstream

I am doing Python client HTTPSConnection.request('POST', url, data, headers) in python.
The data is **b'1502944466046'** which is request body

Debug print shows:

send: b'POST /path/to/someresource HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 172.1.2.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nContent-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\nAccept: application/xml\r\nAuthorization: Basic encodeduserPwd==\r\n\r\n'

send: b'1502944466046'

On Java server, I get org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not 1 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen 1... @1:1)

The data for the POST is just the 'data' variable below derived as follows:

```
name = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000))) # time in millisec used
data = name.encode('utf-8')
```

The Java REST controller has a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value=sameurlaspythonurlabove, method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createMyObject(@RequestBody String name)
```

The method is not hit because of the exception above.

The body is not XML, but server is trying to parse XML, I think, from error above.

If I set Content-type = 'text/plain', then server gives org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Any ideas how to circumvent?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code is expecting XML but you are giving it JSON that starts with 1.you can convert your request body in xml format then you can try.

Comment: Yes, I just succeeded with a <string> </string> encapsulation. Thanks.